# Validity of Monte Carlo

Tags: algorithms, monte-carlo

My question regards the fundamental validity of the concept of Monte Carlo. In the text where I learned about Monte Carlo some time ago and also on all resources I found on the internet, all authors seem to be brushing over the same thing. Typically, people say they want to get an idea of what an expectation such as
 $\mathbb{E}X$ for some random variable $X$ might look like.Then defining the 'sample average' 
$$X^N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N X_i$$, we have the SLLN which says that 
$$\mathbb{P}\{w \in \Omega:X^N(w) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}X\}=1$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.This is then considered a 'proof' of why it makes sense to simulate the same random variable repeatedly and take the average which gives a good approximation of $\mathbb{E}X$. On the other hand what we are really programming is $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N X(w^i).$$
So in the upper example we are summing over multiple random variables and in practice we are summing over stochastic samples $\omega$ of the same random variable. Can somebody please help to put these things together?

Comment: Isn't a realization of the sum of the random variables the same as the sum of the realizations of the random variables?

Comment: I don't see any problem, random variable is a sample of random process. So, $X(w^i) = X_i$

Comment: Actually, I think I see the source of confusion now. I think that you are saying that you actually sample elements of $\Omega$ somehow, and then plug them into a real-valued function $X$. (For instance, technically one can always do this with $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)=([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. In this case $X$ is called the quantile function.) But then, what you have are iid $\Omega$-valued random variables. Passing these to the deterministic function $X$ then creates iid $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables. So it is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, guys. I think I narrowed my problem down to the way I have written down the SLLN. Let's take one $w$ from $\Omega$ that converges such that $X^N(w)\rightarrow EX$. Now, certainly that does not mean that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N( X_i(w)) \rightarrow EX$. In SSLN statement the $w$ is more like a 'summarising' $w$ of all the various $w$ that are plugged into the various $X_i$.

Comment: I mean this is actually the notion of the SSLN. If you have iid random variables, then no matter what $w$ you draw for each one of them, the average of your values will converge. Then MC is also valid. So in essence everything boils down to the definition of SLLN and the fact that somehow lots of $w$ are 'hidden'in one $w$ of the average $X^N$.

Comment: @sbm You can't get away with fixing $\omega$ *and* taking $X$ to be a single function, for then you will be averaging constants. Either the $\omega$ need to vary (so you are composing various $\Omega$-valued random variables with a deterministic function) or the $X$ need to vary (so you are applying different functions to the same element of $\Omega$). We usually say everything the second way.